# Terraform using --var-file and also -var

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In `terraform` i have a variable file `(.tfvars)`and the content of it looks like below

```
instance_size="M4.large"
location="us-east-2"
```

while applying terraform i am using the code like below

```
terraform apply -var-file="/path/variablefile.tfvars"
```

I want to override the `location` to `us-east-1` but do not want to change the `us-east-2` in `.tfvars` file, so can i use the below command that has both `-var` and `-var-file`?

```
terraform apply -var "location=us-east-1" -var-file="/path/variablefile.tfvars"
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with your current command. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin no errors, but it is not working as well

Comment: It would be better to leave the default value of `location` as `us-east-2` in the variable definition and override it within the `terraform.tfvars` file when needed.

Comment: I have so many values, not only one

Comment: I don't understand. So many values for what exactly?

Comment: There is really no programming language that will allow multiple value inputs for the same variable in the same interface/hierarchy level. @MarkoE comment above seems the best path forward.

Comment: Terraform has its variable precedence which takes command-line option as a last value. You cannot assign multiple values for single variable in any option.

Answer (score 2):

From terraform [doc](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables):

```
Any -var and -var-file options on the command line, in the order they are provided.
```

Therefore you just have to swap the position of `-var-file` and `-var`

`terraform apply -var-file="/path/variablefile.tfvars" -var="location=us-east-1"`